# Joomla, Falang integrate component... Fatal error: Call to a member function getTable() on null

Tags: php, joomla-3.3.x, xml, multilingual

Hello I am having some issues for integrate a custom component of joomla in Falang for multilanguage website

Debugging I got null:

> *Fatal error: Call to a member function getTable() on null*
>
> *object(ContentObject)[183] public '_contentElement' => null*

My XML for integrate my component looks as:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <falang type="contentelement">
      <name>Members</name>
      <author>Stackoverflow.com</author>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <description>Definition for the core Members component</description>
      <copyright>stackoverflow.com</copyright>
      <reference>
        <table name="chambercommerce_members">
            <field type="referenceid" name="id" translate="0">ID</field>
            <field type="titletext" name="company_name" translate="1">Company Name</field>
            <field type="text" name="country" translate="1">Country</field>
            <field type="text" name="benefits_discounts" translate="1">Benefits</field>
            <field type="text" name="web" translate="0">Web</field>
        </table>
      </reference>
      <translationfilters>
         <frontpage>id</frontpage>
         <keyword>company_name</keyword>
         <id>id</id>
      </translationfilters>
    </falang>
```

I make my xml looking the others one in my joomla installation for falang and there is this var_dump.

```
<em>object(ContentObject)[180]  public '_contentElement' => object(ContentElement)[179]  public '_xmlFile' => ...</em>
```

Any help for fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it.

The issue: xml name should be iqual to database table name. SO I rename to **mytable.xml** and it worked perfectly

Comment: can you help me tell me how what name in where I found it on database please